# local declaration of 'homeViewController' hides instance variable warning IOS error

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

```
    //Skip straight to main home view
    MySpyHomeViewController *homeViewController = [[MySpyHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
```

I use the above code to skip straight to a view if the user is already logged into the application.

I receive an error on the last line. local declaration of 'homeViewController' hides instance variable warning.

I have read some other threads such as this: [local declaration hides instance variable warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470502/local-declaration-hides-instance-variable-warning)
I do not understand completely why this error occurs. Can someone e

Answer (score 1):

If you have declared the variable `homeViewController` in your header (`.h`) file then putting the above code in your implementation (`.m`) file means that the instance (global) variable won't be set to an instance of `MySpyHomeViewController`, instead a local variable is instantiated and set to an instance of `MySpyHomeViewController`.

To get around this, you need to change the first line of code so it looks something like this if homeViewController is intended to be an instance of `MySpyHomeViewController`:

```
//Skip straight to main home view
homeViewController = [[MySpyHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
```

Otherwise, you need to rename this variable to something else so it doesn't conflict with the name of the global variable

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have an instance variable in the same scope, and its name is `homeViewController`.

So you want to avoid the ambiguity by renaming your temporary:

```
MySpyHomeViewController * homeView = [[MySpyHomeViewController alloc] 
                          ^^^^^^^^              initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.navController =
  [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeView];
                                                             ^^^^^^^^
```

---

In more detail, your sample appears in an instance method, and the class implementing that method has an instance variable named `homeViewController` -- an instance variable may be declared in many places in objc, such as:

---

```
@interface MONClass : NSObject
{
@private
  HomeViewController * homeViewController;
}
```

---

```
@interface MONClass ()
{
  HomeViewController * homeViewController;
}
```

---

```
@implementation MONClass
{
  HomeViewController * homeViewController;
}
```

---

```
@interface MONClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) HomeViewController * homeViewController;
@end


@implementation MONClass
@synthesize homeViewController = homeViewController;
@end
```

Comment: Rather than renaming your temporary, you should rename your ivar to `_homeViewController` (or with the new compiler, just remove the synthesize and it'll do that for you).

Comment: @RobNapier merely a difference in conventions, which there are multiple of in existence.

Comment: Thanks, I declare the var in the interface as 

    property (nonatomic, strong) MySpyHomeViewController *homeViewController;

Am I unable to use this var/why does it create the local. should the above be changed?

@justin - how do i ensure i have the new compiler and where should i check this?

Comment: @StuartM you *are* able to use it. the name is used by the existing declaration (the ivar) -- think of it it being equivalent to `void f() { int a; int a; }` -- so just choose another name for the local variable (not the property), as i outlined in my answer (`homeView`). Xcode from the App Store is new enough.