# Local declaration of 'textField' hides instance variable

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, ios4, xcode4.2

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITEXTField *)textField 
{ 
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; 
    NSLog(@"text === %@",textField.text); 
    NSString *str = [NSStringWithFormat:@"%@",textField.text]; 
    NSLog(@" str --- %@",str);

    SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];      
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondController animated:YES]; 
    [secondController release]; 
}
```

Comment: Please tell what is the problem. You have just given code.

Comment: Please provide more detail. We are not getting what you want.

Comment: As @Mital suggested, please change the UITextField instance name to something other than "textField"

Comment: possible duplicate of [local declaration hides instance variable warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470502/local-declaration-hides-instance-variable-warning)

Answer (score 3):

It may possible that you have declared same `UITextField` name as `textField`. For example, it may possible that you have declared in `.h` file or in `.m` file as below:

```
IBOutlet UITextField * textField;
```

Check for `textfield`.

Comment: Class name UITEXTField is misspelled.  Not sure how the code compiles.  This answer is probably right about the cause.  The test for your hypothesis (and the solution, which you don't make explicit) is to rename the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `UITextField` delegate method `textFieldShouldReturn:` provides an argument to the caller to tell about the source textfield instance. As it occurs, your instance variable has the same name `textField` as the one that delegate method is providing. 
So to avoid the warning , change the argument name in the delegate method definition as

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)aTextField{
```

Also the method expects a Boolean value in return. You should provide it in your method definition